# xmlhttprequest not working in cordova

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cordova

I am trying to use the data passed by a php file on company's server. Here is codes used in the index.js file on cordova side to access the php file:

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var xmlhttp;
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }else{
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Mincrosoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        var url = "http://localhost:8888/notificationProcess.php";

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            var userInfo = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            document.getElementById("firstname").value = 'succeed';
        };

        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

And the notificationProcess.php file looks good in browser:

```
{"firstname":"Ned","lastname":"stark"}
```

In the file index.html for cordova, there is a input box with id 'firstname'. The content of the php file does not matter since it is just for testing, now the problem is it is not even RUNNING this function since the input box is always empty. I also tried the normal ajax method and getJSON method, but none of them works.

Here are the sample codes:

```
var getData = function(){
    var url="http://localhost:8888/notificationProcess.php";
    $.getJSON(url,function(result){
    $.each(result, function(i, field){
        document.getElementById("firstname").value = 'firstname';
    });
    });
};
```

And:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:8888/notificationProcess.php",
}).done(function (data) {
    alert('success');
}).fail(function (a, b, c) {
    console.log(b + '|' + c);
});
```